# Use InvokeMember to get a collection

Tags: powershell, com

I'm trying to use PowerShell to interact with SAP's Universe Design Tool (UDT) via its COM SDK.

I've had success getting/setting the root object's properties:

```
# create UDT instance
$designer = New-Object -ComObject Designer.Application

# get the version
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Version",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$designer,$null)
14.2.4.2410

# make UDT visible
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Visible",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$designer,$true)

# quit UDT
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Quit",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $designer, $null, $null, $null, $null)
```

But I can't seem to access other classes and collections, specifically the Universes collection:

```
# get a reference to the collection
$universes = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Universes", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $designer, $null);

# open a file
$path = "c:\users\x\desktop\foo.unv"
$universe = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Open", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $designer, $null, $null, $path);
```

The class hierarchy from Object Browser:

[image]

The interface's members:

[image]

The `Open` method's signature:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to instantiate an instance of the `Designer.Universe` class before you can get a property from it...